# Amazon SNS to push topic using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to understand amazon php sdk for AWS but I really can't use it.
I find some basic classes to create, display and push topic but I doesn't work either.
I just want to find a way (the simplest way) to push a topic from my website.

Comment: No error messages or code which you have tried?

Comment: Hi, did you make it work? I am searching for the same thing. If you please don't mind can you assist me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I success to do it by using this classes->
[Amazon-SNS-client-for-PHP](https://github.com/ukd1/Amazon-SNS-client-for-PHP)

Very good, easy to use and working just great.

Comment: Whatever works best for you of course - I just want to stress again for later readers, that the code you are using is 2 years old (i.e. apparently not maintained) and especially constrained to SNS only, whereas the official [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) covers most available AWS services with a consistent class design and is regularly updated with new features, security and performance fixes etc. as well; it works just fine in principle, so I highly recommend anyone to have a look at it first before resorting to respectively limited solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I know this code is limited but I only wanted to use SNS and not to use all library.
Addition to this AWS SDK manual very week for php and Its really hard to understand. But your answer good as well

Comment: I agree with @SteffenOpel on the "use the official and supported code" advice, but i recognise the lack of documentation available for the library.

Answer (score 20):

First and foremost, to get acquainted with [Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/), I recommend to perform all required step manually once via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) as explained in the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/Welcome.html?r=9250), i.e. [Create a Topic](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/CreateTopic.html), [Subscribe to this Topic](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/Subscribe.html) and [Publish a message to it](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/Publish.html).

Afterwards it should be fairly straight forward to facilitate the sample fragments provided in the documentation of the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) running, see e.g. method [publish()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#publish) within class AmazonSNS:

```
$sns = new AmazonSNS();

// Get topic attributes
$response = $sns->publish(
    'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:9876543210:example-topic',
    'This is my very first message to the world!',
    array(
        'Subject' => 'Hello world!'
    )
);

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

For a more complete example you might want to check out the the example provided in [Sending Messages Using SNS [...]](http://agileblaze.com/blog/sending-messages-using-sns-sqs-along-with-the-push-notification-using-urbanairship/).

If none of this works out, you'll have to provide more details regarding the specific problems you are encountering, as requested by [tster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697234/amazon-sns-to-push-topic-using-php/9856029#comment12366291_9697234) already.

Good luck!

Comment: Worth noting: if you include Subject then any SMS will not display the actual message.

Answer (score 5):

As told to you by @SteffenOpel, you should once try to perform all required steps manually once via the AWS Management Console.

Then you may use the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html)(v3) `as below` to **create the SNS client**(or infact any service's client, surely with some changes) and then to **create a SNS Topic**.

```
<?php
    //assuming that use have downloaded the zip file for php sdk
    require 'C:/wamp/www/aws sdk/aws-autoloader.php'; //Change the path according to you
    use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;



    try{
            /*-------------METHOD 1----------------*/
            // Create a new Amazon SNS client using AWS v3
            //$sns = new Aws\Sns\SnsClient([
            $sns = new SnsClient([

                'region' => 'us-west-2', //Change according to you
                'version' => '2010-03-31', //Change according to you
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => '<Your root AWS Key',
                    'secret' => '<Your root AWS Secret>',
                ],
                'scheme' => 'http', //disables SSL certification, there was an error on enabling it 

            ]);

            $result = $sns -> createTopic([
            'Name' => '<Your Topic>',
            ]);


        /*-------------METHOD 2----------------*/
        /*
        // Create a new Amazon SNS client using AWS v2
        $sns = SnsClient::factory(array(

            'region' => 'us-west-2',
            'version' => '2010-03-31',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => '<Your root AWS Key',
                'secret' => '<Your root AWS Secret>',
            ],
            'scheme' => 'http',
        ));


        $result = $sns -> createTopic([
            'Name' => '<Your Topic>',
            ]);

        */



        /*-------------METHOD 3----------------*/
        /*
        // Create a new Amazon SNS client using AWS SDK class
        // Use the us-west-2 region and latest version of each client.
        $sharedConfig = [
            'region'  => 'us-west-2',
            'version' => '2010-03-31',

            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => '<Your root AWS Key',
                'secret' => '<Your root AWS Secret>',
            ],
            //'ssl.certificate_authority' => '/path/to/updated/cacert.pem',
            'scheme' => 'http',
        ];

        // Create an SDK class used to share configuration across clients.
        $sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);

        $sns =  $sdk -> createSns();

        $result = $sns -> createTopic([
            'Name' => '<Your Topic>',
            ]);
        */


        if ($result)
            echo "Yes";
        else
            echo "No";
    }

    catch(Exception $e){

        echo 'Caught Exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";

    }


?>
```

**NOTE: This code illustrates creating the client for SNS in three different methods.**
You may uncomment and use one according to your need.
Method 1 (version 3) is the best if you're creating a single client, else use Method 3. Method 2 is soon gonna depreciate (as its version 2)

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-sns-PublishTopic.php.html), we will have to create a SnsClient and call it's publish method. You can get topic's ARN from AWS console.

```
$SnSclient = new SnsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-03-31'
]);

$message = 'This message is sent from a Amazon SNS code sample.';
$topic = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111122223333:MyTopic';

try {
    $result = $SnSclient->publish([
        'Message' => $message,
        'TopicArn' => $topic,
    ]);
    var_dump($result);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```